# Why exported from figma SVG-file looks different?

Tags: svg, figma

In Figma this [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mxmJ.png) has fancy rounded border. It looks exactly the same if exported as PNG. When exported as svg these rounded borders looks [chopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyF4T.png) even if it [zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSKKy.png)  ([SVG-file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RoGRGnBE0B1rzJAU82FF76-sS4rnJ1N6/view?usp=sharing)).

Comment: I suppose that half of the stroke (that is not participating in the rounded corners) falls outside the svg canvas. You may need to change the viewBox attribute

Comment: Can you give me a link to a sample file where we could see the layers of the button that you're trying to export to SVG?